# Convert programmatically list of values to object

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to convert list of values to object if I have properties names?

What I need to do is this, but create object inside a loop to do with objects with a lot of properties.

```
var input = ["item 1 data","item 2 data",["item3a data","item3b data","item3c data"]];
document.write("Input: " +  JSON.stringify(input) + "<br>");


var output = {ITEM_1:"item 1 data", ITEM_2:"item 2 data", ITEM_3:["item3a data","item3b data","item3c data"] };
document.write("Output: " + JSON.stringify(output) + "<br>");
document.write("Output item 3: " + JSON.stringify(output.ITEM_3));
```

```
// Input:
["item 1 data","item 2 data",["item3a data","item3b data","item3c data"]] 
// Output:
{"ITEM_1":"item 1 data","ITEM_2":"item 2 data","ITEM_3":["item3a data","item3b data","item3c data"]}

// Output item 3:
["item3a data","item3b data","item3c data"]
```

The names of the properties could be on a list.

```
var names = ["ITEM_1","ITEM_2","ITEM_3"];
```

Comment: Please try to be clearer, nobody here knows about your context, it would help us a lot

Comment: What is an example of your input? What is an example of desired output? The mix of input and what I take to be some debug output makes this hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, although there may be more elegant ways.

```
var output= {};
for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
  output[names[i]] = input[i];
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Comment: This will do the same thing as using forEach but should be faster, if speed is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var output = {};
input.map(function(value, i) {
  return output[names[i]] = value
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(output))
```

```js
var input = ["item 1 data","item 2 data",["item3a data","item3b data","item3c data"]];
var names = ["ITEM_1","ITEM_2","ITEM_3"];
var output = {};
input.map(function(value, i) {
  return output[names[i]] = value
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the input and add items to your result one by one:

```
var propertyList = ["ITEM_1","ITEM_2","ITEM_3"]; //your list of property names
var result = {}; //start with an empty object
input.forEach(function(item,index){ //for each item in your input
    result[propertyList[index]]=item; //add one to your result using the respective property name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to line up the list items with property names when making an object.

```
function listToObject(list, properties) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         obj[properties[i]] = list[i];
    }
    return obj;
}
```